# the post isn't selected automatically of particular user in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

hi am working on a project where am using multiple user data a user did a post onto the site and when driver see that post he adds their offer to that post but when driver submit the post ...at the admin level the particular is selected automatically but the post is not selected on which he adds price this is my post model.py

```
class Loader_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,related_name="Loader")
    pick_up_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    destination_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    receiver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

## this is my second model of adding price to a particular post

```
class price(models.Model):
    my_post = models.ForeignKey(Loader_post, related_name='prices')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, default='')
    driver_price = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

## this is my adding price to the post views.py

```
@login_required
def add_price_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Loader_post, pk=pk)
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = price_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ps = form.save(commit=False)
            ps.user = request.user
            ps.status = True
            ps.post =  post
            ps.save()
            return redirect('Driver:Driverview')
    else:
        form = price_form()
    return render(request, 'price_form.html', {'form': form})
```

this is my html add post button

```
{% for loader in Loader %}
```

this is loop and this is button

```
<a href="{% url 'Driver:price' pk=loader.pk %}" class="btn btn-full">add price</a>
```

## you can see my_post is select automatically

[image: my_post is not selecting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model the field name is my_post while in the add_price_to_post you are adding ps.post. change that to ps.my_post.

Comment: Glad to help. Select as the answer if it helped you.